# Topological theta-term as a background electric/magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, topology

The topological $\theta$-term in the Schwinger model (1+1-dimensional QED) can be interpreted as a background electric field, as explained in Chapter 7.1.2 of [Tong's lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/gt.pdf). The same holds true for 1+1-dimensional QCD, as pointed out in [this paper by Witten](http://physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/EP/witten_nc_51a_325_79.pdf).

Now my question is: (how) does this change when we go to 3+1 dimensions?

I've read in several papers (e.g. by [Lüscher](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269378904872?via%3Dihub) or [Dvali](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.06317.pdf)) that the $\theta$-term in 4-dimensional QCD gives rise to an (electric) non-Abelian background field. If this statement is true, why don't we get a non-Abelian *magnetic* background field as well? What happens if we go to compact 4-dimensional QED, which also exhibits a physical $\theta$-term, as pointed out in [this paper by Polyakov](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321377900864)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\theta$-term exists in all even $2n$ dimensions and the integral is over $F^n$, where the exponent denotes the multiplicity of the exterior product of the 2-form $F$ with itself. Locally, this $F^n$ is the derivative of a [Chern-Simons form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_form) and if you read e.g. Dvali's paper that you link closely, it is the "constant electric field" of this Chern-Simons form interpreted as a $2n-1$-dimensional analogue of the usual gauge potential that the $\theta$-angle corresponds to.

In 2 dimensions, the $2n-1 = 1$-dimensional Chern-Simons form is merely $A$, i.e. the vector potential itself, so we indeed obtain a true electric field interpretation of the $\theta$-angle.

In higher dimensions, the Chern-Simons form is **not** the same as the vector potential, but instead a $2n-1$-dimensional higher gauge field and correspondingly, the "constant electric field" associated to it has nothing to do with any constant electromagnetic or gluonic field strength. It is a purely formal analogy.

As for why there appears no "magnetic" field: magnetic fields are sourced by currents in Maxwell's equations, but there are no local sources or sinks for the Chern-Simons form - its theory is exactly analogous to that of the eletromagnetic field in 1+1 dimensions, and it has no propagating degrees of freedom.